# Which software management application should I use

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, software-center, snap-store, discover-software-center

I'm bit confused which app should I use to uninstall software. Is it "Discover", is it "Snap Store", is it "Software"? Sometimes I can do it with apt, but sometimes not. Probably I should remove it the same way I installed it but I do not have such a good memory :)
I run Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with 5.15.0-48 kernel.
I would like just recommendation which software to use for app management.

Comment: "The same way as you installed it" is the general rule of thumb. If you can't remember everything, take notes - we all do!

Comment: "Software" shows all installed packages, packages from repository, manually  installed debs or snaps. It will show under "Details -> Source".

Answer (score 1):

"Discover" is the software management package of the KDE desktop, which is used by Ubuntu Studio. However, if it also ships Ubuntu Software, you can use that as your standard tool to install - remove software: it supports both the classical APT packaging system as the new Snap system.

Be aware: sometimes, you may find two entries of the same program, one as APT and the other as Snap. The Snap version typically may be a more recent version. The drawback of Snap is that it does not integrate so well in the system as an APT package.